# Geopy outputs NoneType

Tags: python, geopy

I wanted to get the latitude and longitude of an adress with geopy. My code is

```
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="EXAMPLE")
location = geolocator.geocode("Wismarsche Straße 393-397 19049 Schwerin")
lat = str(location.latitude)
lon = str(location.longitude)
latLon = str(lat) + ";" + str(lon) + ";"
```

and it outputs `NoneType`.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#geopy-2-0) states that the geocode method returns None when no results are found. In your case, removing 19049 from your query returns a result:

```
location = geolocator.geocode("Wismarsche Straße 393-397 Schwerin")
lat = str(location.latitude)
lon = str(location.longitude)
latLon = str(lat) + ";" + str(lon) + ";"

print(f'Latitude: {lat}, longitude: {lon}, latLon: {latLon}')
```

Ouput:

```
Latitude: 53.6519479, longitude: 11.4073671, latLon: 53.6519479;11.4073671;
```